# I created a table in html using python and I'd like to add those input table values into sql database

Tags: python, html, mysql, sql-server

I am using python to access to html to create a table, and what I'm trying to do is when a user inputs values and click a submit button, all the values will be saved in "students" table. I'm not sure how to use submit button to save all the values (lastname, firstname, midtermgrade, finalgrade, firsthw, secondhw, thirdhw).
I'm not familiar with pymysql and I looked through many websites to find solutions for this problems. I'd accept any advice.

```
import cgitb
import pymysql
cgitb.enable()
print("Content-type: text/html\n")

print('<form method="" action="">',
          '<fieldset>',
              '<legend>Personal information:</legend>',
              'Last name:'
              '<input type="text" name="lastname" value="lastname"><br>',
              'First name:'
              '<input type="text" name="firstname" value="firstname"><br>',
              'MidtermGrade:'
              '<input type="text" name="midtermgrade" value="midtermgrade"><br>',
              'FinalGrade:'
              '<input type="text" name="finalgrade" value="finalgrade"><br>',
              'FirstHW:'
              '<input type="text" name="firsthw" value="firsthw"><br>',
              'SecondHW:'
              '<input type="text" name="secondhw" value="secondhw"><br>',
              'ThirdHW:'
              '<input type="text" name="thirdhw" value="thirdhw"><br>',
              '<br><br>'
              '<input type="submit" value="Submit">',
          '</fieldset>'
     </form>)
```

Make a connection to the DB on the RDS instance.  Replace with your own server and user credentials.

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host=localhost, port=3306, user='username', passwd='password', db='student')
cur = conn.cursor()
```

Some SQL to return some data

```
cur.execute("SELECT * from students")
```

A blank space for cosmetics

Iterate over the result set, print one row at a time

close up the connection

```
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need quite a bit more than a print statement to get a usable form.
You've made an HTML form, but sending user data from it to a server so you can get the values requires a web server.

I suggest you look at **Flask** (or another) Web Framework: http://flask.pocoo.org/
It's fairly easy to get started with, and you'll be able to get your form data as variables in a Python function; then you can call your SQL functions to save them to the DB.
Let us know how you go!

Answer (score 0):

This approach isn't working because you're trying to build the page server-side, then expect input client-side, then do some more server-side work to build the page. However (and I'm not an expert on this myself, so I would appreciate corrections), once you build the page server-side, and send it to the client, you need some form of JavaScript on the client to get any more information from the server (AJAX is a common way).

If you're okay with the `submit` button taking the user to a different page to see the results, you don't need the Javascript. I would structure what you're trying to do like this (keep in mind that I can't test this right now, so you'll have to debug it):

In file `form.html`:

```
<!-- TODO: put the rest of the HTML here -->
<form method="post" action="get_results.py">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal information:</legend>
        Last name:
        <input type="text" name="lastname" value="lastname"><br>
        First name:
        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="firstname"><br>
        MidtermGrade:
        <input type="text" name="midtermgrade" value="midtermgrade"><br>
        FinalGrade:
        <input type="text" name="finalgrade" value="finalgrade"><br>
        FirstHW:
        <input type="text" name="firsthw" value="firsthw"><br>
        SecondHW:
        <input type="text" name="secondhw" value="secondhw"><br>
        ThirdHW:
        <input type="text" name="thirdhw" value="thirdhw"><br>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Note that I filled in the `action` and `method` attributes in the form . This is pure HTML. When the form gets submitted, the user will be redirected to `get_results.py`, which will have to read the POST information attached to the page request by the form.

Something like:

In file `get_results.html`:

```
import cgi
import cgitb
import pymysql

cgitb.enable()

# This *should* get the fields from the previous form.
# I can't test it now though...
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

# this part is almost straight from https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL
import pymysql.cursors

# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                            user='user',
                            password='passwd',
                            db='db',
                            charset='utf8mb4',
                            cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        student_sql = 'INSERT INTO `students` (lastname, firstname) VALUES (%s, %s)'
        cursor.execute(student_sql,(form['lastname'], form['firstname']) )
        # replacing some filed names with '...'. Fill them in
        grade_sql = 'INSERT INTO `grades` (midtermgrade, finalgrade, ...) VALUES (%d, %d, %d, %d)'
        cursor.execute(grade_sql, form['midtermgrade'], form['finalgrade'], ...)
    connection.commit()
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Read a single record
        sql = "SELECT * FROM students"
        cursor.execute(sql))
        for result in cursor.fetchall():
            print(result, '<br>')
finally:
    connection.close()
```

That's probably the simplest way to do it. However, and this is important to know, *this approach WILL NOT scale to larger projects*. 
For starters, you'll want:

- a templating languages, so you can separate your raw HTML and code inserted into it
- URL manipulation (so something like mysite.com//grades will take users straight to their grades)
- User authentication (don't want students looking at other students grades do we?)
- an ORM instead of dealing with your database directly (I don't place as much stock in this, but some people swear by it)

If you're trying to make something much larger than this, look into a framework like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) for Python, or any number of other solutions for other languages.